# Want to Integrate Google Calender In my App

Tags: android

I want to develop an android app in which I want to integrate Google Calendar .This is my first app. N nm not getting to start from where please help ... I included calendarview in my xml file but its not working properly n throwing an error of saying "class could not be found "

Comment: Please use the search engine of your choice first before asking such a question here on SO.

Comment: Search engine or not - you need to concretise your question. Are you looking for documentation on how to integrate Google Calendar or are you looking for help on the "class not found"-issue? You have a much better chance of getting a good answer on Stack Overflow if your question is specific and detailed.

Comment: View requires API level 11 (current min is (WHAT DO YOU HAVE?):